# Flask Render template with Ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask, post

Main Problem: **Display HTML Page**

I am making a post in Ajax from a string, named result, to my backend in flask.

[Ajax post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D55ZX.png)

I can receive the variable in flask, and then use it in the following functions.  However, I can't make render_template to another HTML page afterwards.

[Flask route with render template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zycwm.png)

In the app I press the button associated with that route, but nothing happens, it stays on the same page. Pressing the back button in the browser, the web page I want to show, appears.

Comment: if u want to redirect user who initiated the ajax post, you should send in your response the URL to redirect and then in your JS script trigger the redirect with `window.location.href  = <the redirect url>`

Comment: I' ve tried that way and it doesn't work. @ilias-sp